# pi.hardware_PWM() not works together with flask IntegerField nor StringField

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, gpio, pwm

I have to use `pigpiod`, `pi.hardware_PWM()` as it gives me beautiful squrewave.
I've created a webserver, in which I use `flask` and `flask-wtf`. I fetch the number from the user with `IntegerField`, which I would like to use as a PWM control number.

However I get an error message:

> error: cannot convert argument to integer
>   extents = [struct.pack("I", PWMduty)]

I tried to make the number an integer with `int(variable name)`, but this gives an error message as well.

> TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'IntegerField' 
>   pi.hardware_PWM(12, 200, int(form.one_white))

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You access the value of a form field through its `data` attribute, e.g. `forminstance.field.data`, which I think in your case would translate to `form.one_white.data`.

Comment: @SuperShoot, you got the answer! it is works! first I receive NoneType, but with a try excpet it is solved;)
Thank you Mate! i wsa struggeling since days!

Comment: Glad to hear mate.

Comment: @ZoltánGál If you have a solution then write an answer and mark it as correct in 2 days.

Comment: @eyllanesc all right, thx for the suggestion, I did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thx for @SuperShoot i have the answer to my problem!

instead of

```
    form.one_white
```

I have to use

```
    for.one_white.data
```

where the "form" directs to my form.py file and the "one_white" is an IntegerField variable.

works pretty fine, due to the way how I made the code I had to add a try-except method, because first there is no value, so I got ValueError